# 3rd Party Libraries with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Im trying to add a single React component to company site that does not use React. I followed the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) to add a single react component to the HTML and got that working. I am trying to utilize this component for GSAP animations(3rd party animation library) based on state change and such. I have already included the CDN scripts for GSAP and it works on the rest of the application, but I am struggling trying to use inside my React component.

If I try "import {gsap} from gsap/...", after installing the NPM package  I get an error saying "cant import outside of modules, if I try using "require", I get an error saying "require is not defined. Lastly, if I just try writing gsap without trying to import in my component it says gsap is undefined.

How can I use 3rd party libraries inside my react component when it is a standalone component and not in a react app.

```html
'use strict';





class TeamMembers extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   
    this.state = { selectedGroup: "leadership", activeMember: 0};
  }


  render() {
    let selectedMembers = [];
      for (let i=0; i < employees.length; i++) {
        if(employees[i].group == this.state.selectedGroup) {
          selectedMembers.push(employees[i])
        }
      }
      
    return (
      <div className="team-wrapper">
     <div className="teams">
      <h1 onClick={() => this.setState({ selectedGroup: "leadership"})}>Leaders</h1>
      <h1 onClick={() => this.setState({ selectedGroup: "creative"})}>Creative</h1>
      <h1>Digital Marketing</h1>
      <h1>Project Management</h1>
      <h1>Content Development</h1>
     </div>
        
      <div className="team-members-container1">
        <div className="team-list">
         {
           selectedMembers.map((member,i) => 
           <div className={this.state.activeMember == i ? "list-item active" : "list-item inactive"}  onClick={() => this.setState({ activeMember: i})}  key={i}><div className="member-name"> <svg id={this.state.activeMember == i ? "arrow-active": 'arrow'} ref={this.myRef} data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 127.05 145.93" fill="#dfe9ff"><polygon class="cls-1" points="125.71 145.93 126.38 72.96 127.05 0 63.52 35.9 0 71.81 62.85 108.87 125.71 145.93"/></svg>{member.name}</div><span>{member.title}</span></div>)
         }
          
        </div>
      <img src="./teamdemo.png"/>
  
    
           <article>{selectedMembers[this.state.activeMember].bio}</article>
     
    
    
    </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

let domContainer = document.querySelector('.team-members-container');
ReactDOM.render(<TeamMembers/>, domContainer);
```

Comment: Why don't you try the react version of the same library?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gsap

Comment: My problem is the imports, I still cant import anything without getting the same error of "cant import outside of module"?